# Multidimensional arrays. Push and then join

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Lets say I have the following,

```
var array1 = ["10", "11"],
    array2 = ["AAA", "BBB"],
    result = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++ ) {
  result.push( [ array1[i], array2[i] ] );
}

alert(result);
```

I get `["10","AAA","11","BBB"]`.

How can I incorporate a `join` function, or any other function that would allow me to get the following output:

`["10_AAA","11_BBB"]`.

Comment: Why not simply `result.push( array1[i] + '_' + array2[i] );` ?

Comment: Thanks! Such a facepalm moment for me...

Comment: As you are creating an array that you push, you result will actually be `[["10", "AAA"], ["11", "BBB"]]` rather than `["10", "AAA", "11", "BBB"]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't join the items, as they are in different arrays. For your example with just two arrays, you could just concatenate the strings:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++ ) {
  result.push( array1[i] + "_" + array2[i] );
}
```

You *could* use join, if you create an array on the fly from the items in each array, that syntax may be easer if you have more than two arrays to concatenate items from:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++ ) {
  result.push( [ array1[i], array2[i] ].join("_") );
}
```

Comment: i don't think there is a function for that... seems you have to concat values.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
for ( var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++ ) {
  result.push(array1[i] + '_' + array2[i]);
}
```

Comment: See my edit once if you print $result will give same result....first check and downvote it

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, you can use join, for example like this :

```
for ( var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++ ) {
  result.push( [ array1[i], array2[i] ].join('_' );
}
```

but why not simply use `result.push( array1[i] + '_' + array2[i] );` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just join them:

```
result.push( [ array1[i], array2[i] ].join('_') );
```